# Is grouping only one element in a fieldset an accessibility problem?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I have a long form with a structure as in the picture below:

[image: a form with 3 fieldsets, 2 of which contain only 1 input]

There will usually be only a single input element in the group, but there may be more.

### My question is (in terms of accessibility)

1. Can a group contain only a single input? For example,

```html
<div role="group" aria-describedby="title">
  <p id="title">Name</p>
  <label for="name">Your name:
    <input id="name">
  </label>
</div>
```

2. **If not**, is it right to do so in order to maintain uniformity?

I couldn't find a proper answer for this question in the WCAG.

I would greatly appreciate it if sources could be provided. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a WCAG rule that forbids this pattern, but it is more confusing to screen reader users. That's because the same information will be announced twice, e.g.: "Hobbies grouping Hobby edit". And it's not only the screen readers - I find the duplicate information questionable from UX perspective as well. Maybe you can restructure the form to group multiple inputs.

Comment: @DarekKay thanks. The thing is in most of the places the title added more (and different) details. I'm preferring to make a global solution, but don't want it to be too much verbose.

Comment: I think you are approaching this from the wrong angle, why not change the style of the `<fieldset>` so it looks uniform without having to wrap it around single inputs? Additionally if you are going for uniformity make sure labels appear **either** before an input or to the left of it, you have a mix of both. You could style the fieldset to just be a horizontal border top and bottom for example and then your form would look uniform. Darek is right, you should not wrap a single input in a fieldset as it adds too much unneeded noise.